# How to intercept WM_DELETE_WINDOW on OSX using Tkinter

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, tkinter

I'm trying to keep a Toplevel window from being closed in OSX by intercepting window manager WM_DELETE_WINDOW event.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *

def speak():
    print "woof"

root = Tk()
root.title("root")
win = Toplevel()
win.title("win")
win.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', speak)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this I get two pop up windows titled "root" and "win".  If I click on the red "x" close button on "win" to close the window, prints "woof" and then closes.  However, if I run this same code on windows "win" stays open and keeps printing "woof" every time I click the red "x" close button.

How can I keep the Toplevel window from closing on OSX when I click the red "x" close button?

Answer (score 2):

See the reply to [Python Issue 12584](http://bugs.python.org/issue12584).  It appears to be a bug in the very buggy Cocoa Tcl/Tk 8.5 that Apple shipped with OS X 10.6.  Don't use it or the Apple-supplied Pythons in 10.6 if you are using Tkinter or anything that uses Tkinter, like IDLE.  More info [here](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).