# Keep child window above parent

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to keep a child window above a parent on OS X

I've tried searching google, but I haven't been able to find anything that worked.

I'm a newbie to python and OS X as a whole, so I might be missing something simple.

I am using python3.4 along with OS X 10.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def childWindow (self,parent):
        window = Toplevel(parent)

        self.style = Style()

        self.style.theme_use("default")

        window.wm_title('Child')

        message = "This is the child window"

        Label(window, text=message).pack()

        Button(window, text='Close', command=window.destroy).pack(padx=2.5,pady=2.5)

        # Lift above parent
        window.lift(aboveThis=parent) 

        # Disable parent
        window.grab_set() 

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Root")

        self.style = Style()

        self.style.theme_use("default")

        b1 = Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)

        b2 = Button(self, text='test: Child Window', command=lambda: self.childWindow (self))

        b1.pack(side=LEFT,padx=2.5,pady=2.5)

        b2.pack(side=LEFT,padx=2.5,pady=2.5)

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def main():
    root = Tk()

    app = Example(root)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here. I tried your sample on my OS X Desktop and the Child Windows is most definitely above the parent and is modal in behavior.

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803686/tk-modal-dialog-in-python

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite explain myself properly. I forgot to add that it doesn't stay on top of the parent window when I use grab_set()
I can reactivate the parent window (although it remains disabled)

I found the solution in the question above. I don't know why I didn't look at transient() more closely. Thanks for your help.