# How to compulsory close message box for Toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

[image for  that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW0w8.png)
I have few lines of code here which is login system which works fine but i can click on the `Toplevel` button multiple times when i provide the wrong password without closing the `messagebox`.How can i make it so that it has to be closed `messagebox` before i can make attempt again.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def top():
    if entry1.get() == "333":
       log.destroy()
       root.deiconify()
    else:
       messagebox.showerror("error", "try again")


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

log = Toplevel(root)
log.geometry("200x200")


label1 = Label(log, text="password")
entry1 = Entry(log)
button1 = Button(log, text="login", command=top)

label1.pack()
entry1.pack()
button1.pack(side="bottom")

lab = Label(root, text="welcome bro").pack()


root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a modal dialog in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803686/how-to-create-a-modal-dialog-in-tkinter)

Comment: I  tried grab_set()  and wait_window() it didn't work.

Comment: `grab_set()` should work if you build own message box using `Toplevel()` - see [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Comment: BTW: on Linux I can't click many times on `login` button - I have to close `messagebox`. So it may depends on System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With hint from @furas this how to implement this:

create another function to the call it when the entry doesn't match  and use  grab_set method  for the Toplevel window `tp.grab_set()`.You can add your customarised image to the Toplevel window as well as message to display in the box(here: i use label to depict that)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox



def dialog():  #  this function to call when entry doesn't match 
    tp = Toplevel(log)
    tp.geometry("300x100")
    tp.title('error')
    tp.grab_set()  # to bring the focus to the window for you to close it
    tp.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    l = Label(tp, text="try again\n\n\n\n add your customarize image to the window")
    l.pack()


def top():
    if entry1.get() == "333":
    log.destroy()
    root.deiconify()
else:
    dialog()  # being called here 


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

log = Toplevel(root)
log.geometry("200x200")


label1 = Label(log, text="password")
entry1 = Entry(log)
button1 = Button(log, text="login", command=top)

label1.pack()
entry1.pack()
button1.pack(side="bottom")

lab = Label(root, text="welcome bro").pack()


root.withdraw()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the toplevel won't flash and have the bell() effect when you make several attempt to click on the button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the log window the parent of the dialog:

```
messagebox.showerror("error", "try again", parent=log)
```

By default it will use the root window (the `Tk` instance) as the parent which in this case is not what you want.

Comment: It makes the window to freeze when i click the root window again unless i close the it with task manager before i can run again

Comment: My answer is intended for the code you posted, where you cannot click the root window because it is withdrawn.

Comment: This answer works may be OS factor am using Windows 7