# How to make new label when the program is running in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a new label when the program is running when the button is pressed. I am working in Tkinter python v3.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import copy

class App(ttk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master):
    self.newwindow = master
    self.pocetnik_label = Label(master, text = 'Pocetnik')
    self.pocetnik_label.pack(side = LEFT)

    self.dodaj_button = Button(master, text = '+', command = self.pocetnik)
    self.dodaj_button.pack(side = RIGHT)
    self.newwindow.mainloop()

def pocetnik(self):
    b2= tk.Toplevel(self.newwindow)

    self.ime_label = Label(b2, text = 'Ime').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self.ime_entry = Entry(b2, bd = 5).grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    self.vreme_label = Label(b2, text = 'Vreme').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    self.vreme_entry = Entry(b2, bd = 5).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    self.napravi_button = Button(b2, text = 'Napravi').grid(row = 3, column = 0)

master = Tk()
pocetnik = App(master)
```

Comment: Explain better your problem, be more detailed, what is the problem and which button should create a new label?

Comment: @Mat.C I want  button napravi to make new label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked your code on my computer and it kind of works :-)
If I press the '+' button a new window appears.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import copy


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.newwindow = master
        self.pocetnik_label = Label(master, text='Pocetnik')
        self.pocetnik_label.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.dodaj_button = Button(master, text='+', command=self.pocetnik)
        self.dodaj_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.newwindow.mainloop()

    def pocetnik(self):
        b2 = tk.Toplevel(self.newwindow)

        self.ime_label = Label(b2, text='Ime').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.ime_entry = Entry(b2, bd=5).grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.vreme_label = Label(b2, text='Vreme').grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.vreme_entry = Entry(b2, bd=5).grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.napravi_button = Button(b2, text='Napravi').grid(row=3, column=0)


master = Tk()
pocetnik = App(master)
```

Maybe you want to become this new window a modal dialoge? You could have a look at [How to create a modal dialog in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803686/how-to-create-a-modal-dialog-in-tkinter)