# how to create a pop up massage in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popup

[image]
firstly what do you call this popup and how do you create it in python?

I don't know what do you call it, that's why I couldn't create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the tkinter library in python.

Please see this solution [How to create a modal dialog in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803686/how-to-create-a-modal-dialog-in-tkinter)

Answer (score -2):

This can be done with the win10toast module in python, more information can be found here on the PyPi website https://pypi.org/project/win10toast/

Note: This will not create exactly what is referenced in the picture above, but instead it creates a notification at the bottom right of a windows 10 machine.