# CTkMessagebox and tkinter messagebox.showinfo() problems

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, messagebox, customtkinter

I am trying to create a custom tkinter program. For a week or so I've been struggling with the messagebox and the interactions between it and the main window. This is the following code:

```
 def check_entries(self):
        if self.api_key_entry.get().strip() != "" and self.api_key_entry.get().strip() != "API Key" and \
            self.api_secret_entry.get().strip() !="" and self.api_secret_entry.get().strip() !="API Secret":

            self.api_hashed_key = self.hasher.hash(self.api_key_entry.get().replace(' ',''))
            self.secret_hashed_key = self.hasher.hash(self.api_secret_entry.get().replace(' ', ''))

            self.store_the_keys()

                     
        else:
            self.msg = CTkMessagebox(
                title="Error",
                message="Please fill in both keys",
                justify="center",
                font=("Anita  Semi-square", 20),
                icon="cancel",
                option_1="OK"
                
            )
            self.msg_x = (self.parent.winfo_rootx()) + int(self.msg.width/2)
            self.msg_y = (self.parent.winfo_rooty()) + int(self.msg.height)
            self.msg.geometry(f'+{self.msg_x}+{self.msg_y}')
            self.msg.wait_window()
```

When the CTkMessagebox appears I can't interact with the main window which is what I want. The problem comes when I click on the messagebox or move it (I can also move the main window and the same happens). Then even though it haven't closed the messagebox I can interact with the main window and I want to able to interact with it only when the messagebox is closed.

I tried different approaches like:

```
self.msg.wait_window()

while self.msg.get() != "OK":
       self.grab_set()
self.grab_release()
```

But this didn't seem to work as well. Then I tried implementing the messagebox from tkinter and used showinfo:

```
self.grab_set()
messagebox.showinfo(message="need keys")
self.grab_release()
```

But as before when I clicked on the main window the messagebox minimized and I could once again interact with the main window.

Can anyone suggest any other solutions. The self that I use in the code is a frame the I've appended to the main app and the CTkMessagebox is a custom widget on github: https://github.com/Akascape/CTkMessagebox

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803686/how-to-create-a-modal-dialog-in-tkinter

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped!